# Message: 'Forbidden' when trying to add channel to channel group in PubNub

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I am trying to add a channel to a channel group and associate an auth_key for pub/sub to this channel using this code:

```js
pubnub.channel_group_add_channel({
            callback: function(success) {
                        pubnub.grant({
                            channel: channelName,
                            auth_key: userAuthKeyForChannel,
                            read: true,
                            write: true,
                            ttl:0,
                            callback: function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                                res.status(200).json({response: {ChatChannel: createdRecord}, token:req.token});
                            }
                        });


            },
            error: function(err) { return hlprs.sendResWithErr(res,err,500,true,'Error while trying to add channel to group in our messaging platform'); },
            channel: channelName,
            channel_group: channelGroupName
        });
```

But I always get the response

```js
{ message: 'Forbidden', 
  payload: { 'channel-groups': [ ':90c977bbc169b12054706b0de07dd9f2' ] } 
}
```

When I disable Access Manager in PubNub admin panel, it (obviously) works perfectly. I'd also like to mention that this request takes place in a server backend where pubnub is initialized with subscriber_key, publish_key and secret_key. There are no other pubnub requests prior to this one and there's no one subscribed in other environments.

EDIT: I suppose I need to grant permissions to the backend at the application level before proceeding with adding the channel in a group, however I am unsure how to properly do this.

Comment: This is likely exactly as you describe: **Order of Operations.**  We are reviewing with the team really quick before we post a reply.

Comment: @PubNub I've tried this in tens of different orders while trying to make this work. I've even tried passing the channel group name instead of the channel name in grant(). If the docset is up-to-date and I am not missing something obvious, I believe this is a bug on your end.

Comment: You have to `grant` the **manage** permission on the `channel-group-id`.

Comment: @PubNub oh I see. I don't recall the docs mentioning anything about this. Will try it later today, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How do I secure my Channel Groups and Namespaces?

> Read more about [PubNub JavaScript Stream Controller](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/overview/stream-controller.html#_how_do_i_secure_my_channel_groups_and_namespaces) documentation.

#### Grant access to manage Channel Group

```js
pubnub.grant({
    channel_group : "90c977bbc169b12054706b0de07dd9f2",
    auth_key      : "SUPER_SECRET",
    channel       : channel,
    read          : true,
    write         : true,
    manage        : true,      // <-- Manage Permission TRUE
    callback      : success,
    error         : errorback
});
```

Comment: Linked document does not contain said information any longer. Could you please update it?

Comment: Thank you!  I've confirmed this is true.  We will update this.